# How can I count the amount of extra numbers are given over a base value?

Tags: java, methods

There is a base price and its only applicable when hrs = 50 and ppl = 30. I need to make it so that for each extra hrs or ppl it will charge an additional rate on top of the base rate. I am not sure how to make a piece of code that counts the extra hrs and ppl.

```
public static void streamingCost(int hrs, int ppl, double base, double addRate) {
    hrs = 50;
    ppl = 33;

    base = 25;
    addRate = 2;

    if (hrs == 50 || ppl == 30) {
        double tot = base;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here all you need to do is calculate the extra charge. For each additional hour when ppl = 30, you need to calculate how many extra hours to finalise a total. Alternatively, for each additional person when hrs = 50, you need to calculate how many extra people there are to finalise a total.

This would be your code:

```
public static void streamingCost(int hrs, int ppl, double base, double addRate) {
        hrs = 50;
        ppl = 33;

        base = 25;
        addRate = 2;

        if (hrs == 50 || ppl == 30) {
            if (hrs > 50) {
                int temp = hrs - 50;
                double tot = base + (temp*addRate);
            }
            else if (ppl > 30) {
                int temp = ppl - 30;
                double tot = base + (temp*addRate);
            }
        }
}
```